# Checking to see if page title is in array via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I've created semi-dynamic page titles on a static site by using the following on each page (for example):

```
<?php $title="Example"; ?>
```

And added this to my header file:

```
<title>Company Name Here<?php if ($title!="") { echo " | $title"; } ?></title>
```

That part is working well.

Now, I would like to use jQuery to check if a page title for the ACTIVE page is in an array so that (if it is) I can apply a class to a navigation element or two. And, if it not in the array, I'd remove that class. Like so (in partial pseudocode):

```
if $(title) of currently visible page is in this array(about, page2, page3) {
     $('a#idname').addClass('selected')
} else {
     $('a#idname').removeClass('selected')
}
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this. I'm open to suggestion. I'm just not very clear on the syntax for determining:

1. What page is currently loaded
2. How to use some identifier for the current page to change the class of an element on the page after page load. I know how to do it on click, but as soon as the page loads, the class goes away.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the document's title by accessing the `title` property on the `document` object, `document.title`. In order to get the portion of the string after the pipe, `|`, you could simply split the title on the `|` character and then get the second element in the returned array.

If the page's title is "Company Name Here | About" like in your question, then `document.title.split('|')` would return the array `["Company Name Here ", " About"]`, therefore `.split('|')[1]` would return the string "About".

Use the [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) in order to check if the `title` string is in the  array `titleArray` and then add/remove the class accordingly.

Here is a basic example:

```js
var title = document.title.split('|')[1];
var titleArray = ['About', 'Page2', 'Page3'];

if (title && titleArray.indexOf(title.trim()) > -1) {
  $('span').addClass('selected');
} else {
  $('span').removeClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.selected { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Company Name Here | About</title>
<span>The title is in the array if this is red.</span>
```

Comment: Brilliant, Josh! Thank you. That did the trick. I actually understand all of that with the exception of the [1] following the pipe character in the first line. If you have a moment to elaborate, I'd love to learn that piece. If not, I'll look it up somewhere. Much appreciated! You saved me hours of tinkering.

Comment: @Jenn The `.split()` method returns an array, so `'Company Name Here | About'.split('|')` would return `["Company Name Here ", " About"]` in this case, `[1]` is just accessing the second element (which is the string `"About"`). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Aha! Yep. Makes sense. It splits at that character. Thank you again... I owe you a beer (virtually speaking, I guess).